# Naming private instance variables

Tags: java, oop

I have these two files in Java and my teacher says they work fine but that I need to reduce the amount of private instance variables in my code. How would go you about fixing this?

```
public class CarV7 {

    private String myCarType1, myCarType2, myCarType3;
    private int mySmiles1, mySmiles2, mySmiles3;
    private int myEmiles1, myEmiles2, myEmiles3;
    private double myGals1, myGals2, myGals3;
    private double myPricePerGallon1, myPricePerGallon2, myPricePerGallon3;

    CarV7(String carType, int eMiles, int sMiles, double gals, double pricePerGallon) {
        myCarType1 = carType;
        myCarType2 = carType;
        myCarType3 = carType;
        mySmiles1 = sMiles;
        mySmiles2 = sMiles;
        mySmiles3 = sMiles;
        myEmiles1 = eMiles;
        myEmiles2 = eMiles;
        myEmiles3 = eMiles;
        myGals1 = gals;
        myGals2 = gals;
        myGals3 = gals;
        myPricePerGallon1 = pricePerGallon;
        myPricePerGallon2 = pricePerGallon;
        myPricePerGallon3 = pricePerGallon;
    }

    public int calcDistance(int myEmiles, int sMiles) {
        return myEmiles - sMiles;
    }

    public double calcMPG(int distance, double gals) {
        return distance / gals;
    }

    public double calcGPM(double myGals, int distance) {
        return myGals / distance;
    }

    public double totalCost(double pricePerGallon, double gals) {
        return gals * pricePerGallon;
    }
}
```

```
public class CarV7Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String carType1, carType2, carType3;
        int sMiles1, sMiles2, sMiles3;
        int eMiles1, eMiles2, eMiles3;
        double gals1, gals2, gals3;
        double pricePerGallon1, pricePerGallon2, pricePerGallon3;
        int distance1, distance2, distance3;
        double cost1, cost2, cost3;
        double mpg1, mpg2, mpg3;
        double gpm1, gpm2, gpm3;

        carType1 = "06 Saturn View";
        carType2 = "03 Toyota Camr";
        carType3 = "10 Nissan Leaf";
        sMiles1 = 5678;
        sMiles2 = 5678;
        sMiles3 = 5678;
        eMiles1 = 6015;
        eMiles2 = 6015;
        eMiles3 = 6015;
        gals1 = 15.8;
        gals2 = 17.6;
        gals3 = 14.9;
        pricePerGallon1 = 2.67;
        pricePerGallon2 = 2.8;
        pricePerGallon3 = 2.58;

        CarV7 car1 = new CarV7(carType1, eMiles1, sMiles1, gals1, pricePerGallon1);
        CarV7 car2 = new CarV7(carType2, eMiles2, sMiles2, gals2, pricePerGallon2);
        CarV7 car3 = new CarV7(carType3, eMiles3, sMiles3, gals3, pricePerGallon3);

        distance1 = car1.calcDistance(eMiles1, sMiles1);
        distance2 = car2.calcDistance(eMiles2, sMiles2);
        distance3 = car3.calcDistance(eMiles3, sMiles3);

        cost1 = car1.totalCost(pricePerGallon1, gals1);
        cost2 = car2.totalCost(pricePerGallon2, gals2);
        cost3 = car3.totalCost(pricePerGallon3, gals3);

        mpg1 = car1.calcMPG(distance1, gals1);
        mpg2 = car2.calcMPG(distance2, gals2);
        mpg3 = car3.calcMPG(distance3, gals3);

        gpm1 = car1.calcGPM(gals1, distance1);
        gpm2 = car2.calcGPM(gals2, distance2);
        gpm3 = car3.calcGPM(gals3, distance3);

        System.out.printf("%40s", "Gas Mileage Calculations");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-13s %12s %10s %10s %10s %8s %6s %10s %10s", "Type of Car", "Start Miles", "End     Miles", "Distance", "Gallons", "Price", "Cost", "Miles/Gal", "Gal/Mile");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("=================================================================================================");
        System.out.printf("%-14s %9d %10d %10d %9.1f %8.1f %8.1f %10.3f %9.3f\n", carType1, sMiles1, eMiles1, distance1, gals1, pricePerGallon1, cost1, mpg1, gpm1);
        System.out.printf("%-14s %9d %10d %10d %9.1f %8.1f %8.1f %10.3f %9.3f\n", carType2, sMiles2, eMiles2, distance2, gals2, pricePerGallon2, cost2, mpg2, gpm2);
        System.out.printf("%-14s %9d %10d %10d %9.1f %8.1f %8.1f %10.3f %9.3f\n", carType3, sMiles3, eMiles3, distance3, gals3, pricePerGallon3, cost3, mpg3, gpm3);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type

Comment: why would you want that at first place?Do you know that why are these variables private?

Comment: Why does every car have three of each variable? It looks like you have misunderstood the mechanics of object orientation.

Comment: See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Comment: Apparently I only need one of each

Comment: Could someone check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your declaration of private instance variables to this :

```
private String myCarType1;
private int mySmiles1;
private int myEmiles1;
private double myGals1;
private double myPricePerGallon1;
```

... because the other variables aren't used, at all.

Then change your constructor as follows:

```
CarV7 (String carType, int eMiles, int sMiles, double gals, double pricePerGallon)
{
  myCarType1 = carType;
  mySmiles1 = sMiles;
  myEmiles1 = eMiles;
  myGals1 = gals;
  myPricePerGallon1 = pricePerGallon; 
}
```

Don't change the names of the local variables inside your main method.

```
Finally run the code... it should work.
```

Comment: If my answer is wothy, please accept it by clicking on the tick next to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I need to use the rest of the variables as well, though.

Comment: How do you use rest of the variables

Comment: I have to calculate the 3 distances

Comment: Objects of classes is a runtime instance of a class for example:

Comment: If I set had a mutator method for an instance variable of a class: then when I set the instance variable, for example a variable of type int, to 1 with object ob, and set it to 2 with object obj. With object ob the variabl will hold the value 1 but with obj it will hold the value 2.

Comment: Please ensure you understand what an object is and how it is used, as it is extremely vital in object orientated programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the CarV7 file, you have a large number of instance variables that you're not using within the class. It looks like you're not using anything you set in the constructor.

Comment: I only need one of each but how would I assign them to the rest of the variables?

Comment: When you create a `new CarV7` it creates a distinct instance of the `CarV7` object, each with its own copy of your private variables. So you only need one of each variable type in the object. Further, if you look closely, when you set the value of `myCarType1` in the constructor, you're never actually using it again.

Comment: `CarV7 car1 = new CarV7(carType1, eMiles1, sMiles1, gals1, pricePerGallon1);`
This object will have a myCarType equal to 06 Saturn View



`CarV7 car2 = new CarV7(carType2, eMiles2, sMiles2, gals2, pricePerGallon2);`
This one will have myCarType of 03 Toyota Camr

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need instance variables at all? It seems none of your member methods make use of the instance variables. Hence the methods could be defined as static instead, and you don't even need to instantiate the class in the first place.

Comment: You have a point, but programming practises weren't used in a way that used instance variables effectively in the code, the question should be answered in terms of how the code could include instance variables and make use of them as well as answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I gave your CarV7 class some instance variables.  Since the variables are being set in the constructor, the methods don't need any parameters.

```
package com.ggl.car;

public class CarV7 {

    private int eMiles;
    private int sMiles;

    private double gallons;
    private double pricePerGallon;

    private String carType;

    public CarV7(String carType, int sMiles, int eMiles, 
            double gallons, double pricePerGallon) {
        this.carType = carType;
        this.sMiles = sMiles;
        this.eMiles = eMiles;
        this.gallons = gallons;
        this.pricePerGallon = pricePerGallon;
    }

    public int calcDistance() {
        return eMiles - sMiles;
    }

    public double calcMPG() {
        return (double) calcDistance() / gallons;
    }

    public double calcGPM() {
        return gallons / calcDistance();
    }

    public double totalCost() {
        return gallons * pricePerGallon;
    }

    public int geteMiles() {
        return eMiles;
    }

    public int getsMiles() {
        return sMiles;
    }

    public double getGallons() {
        return gallons;
    }

    public double getPricePerGallon() {
        return pricePerGallon;
    }

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

}
```

I didn't change much in your tester class.  I got rid of the variable types at the beginning of the main method, and set the variable type as I used each variable.

```
package com.ggl.car;

public class CarV7Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String carType1 = "06 Saturn View";
        String carType2 = "03 Toyota Camr";
        String carType3 = "10 Nissan Leaf";
        int sMiles1 = 5678;
        int sMiles2 = 5678;
        int sMiles3 = 5678;
        int eMiles1 = 6015;
        int eMiles2 = 6015;
        int eMiles3 = 6015;
        double gals1 = 15.8;
        double gals2 = 17.6;
        double gals3 = 14.9;
        double pricePerGallon1 = 2.67;
        double pricePerGallon2 = 2.8;
        double pricePerGallon3 = 2.58;

        CarV7 car1 = new CarV7(carType1, sMiles1, eMiles1, gals1, pricePerGallon1);
        CarV7 car2 = new CarV7(carType2, sMiles2, eMiles2, gals2, pricePerGallon2);
        CarV7 car3 = new CarV7(carType3, sMiles3, eMiles3, gals3, pricePerGallon3);

        int distance1 = car1.calcDistance();
        int distance2 = car2.calcDistance();
        int distance3 = car3.calcDistance();

        double cost1 = car1.totalCost();
        double cost2 = car2.totalCost();
        double cost3 = car3.totalCost();

        double mpg1 = car1.calcMPG();
        double mpg2 = car2.calcMPG();
        double mpg3 = car3.calcMPG();

        double gpm1 = car1.calcGPM();
        double gpm2 = car2.calcGPM();
        double gpm3 = car3.calcGPM();

        System.out.printf("%40s", "Gas Mileage Calculations");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-13s %12s %10s %10s %10s %8s %6s %10s %10s", "Type of Car", "Start Miles", "End     Miles", "Distance", "Gallons", "Price", "Cost", "Miles/Gal", "Gal/Mile");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("=================================================================================================");
        System.out.printf("%-14s %9d %10d %10d %9.1f %8.2f %8.2f %10.3f %9.3f\n", car1.getCarType(), sMiles1, eMiles1, distance1, gals1, pricePerGallon1, cost1, mpg1, gpm1);
        System.out.printf("%-14s %9d %10d %10d %9.1f %8.2f %8.2f %10.3f %9.3f\n", car2.getCarType(), sMiles2, eMiles2, distance2, gals2, pricePerGallon2, cost2, mpg2, gpm2);
        System.out.printf("%-14s %9d %10d %10d %9.1f %8.2f %8.2f %10.3f %9.3f\n", car3.getCarType(), sMiles3, eMiles3, distance3, gals3, pricePerGallon3, cost3, mpg3, gpm3);
    }
}
```